# Background color only goes halfway on 2nd page of pdf generated with Puppeteer

Tags: css, puppeteer, background-color, lwc

I am generating a pdf with Puppeteer. When the generated pdf is more than one page, the second page's background color stops where the last div stops. I would like the background color to go to all the way to the bottom of the last page, whether thats two, three, or four pages.
I am generating the html using LWC based on JSON data. The format of the html is as follows:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <main>
      <div class="main">
        <header></header>
        <div class="title"></div>
        <div class="section">{section content #1}</div>
        <div class="section">{section content #2}</div>
        <div class="section">{section content #3}</div>
        <div class="section">{section content #4}</div>
        <footer></footer>
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

What I tried:

```
html, body, main {
  height: 100%
}
.main {
  height: 100%,
  display: flex,
  flex-direction: column
}

.section:last-child {
  flex-grow:1,
  display: flex,
  flex-direction: column,
  justify-content: flex-start
}
```

This is my puppeteer code:

```
async function generatePdf(url) {
  const browser  = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true, args: ['--no-sandbox'] });
  const webPage = await browser.newPage();
  webPage.on('console', msg => console.log('PAGE LOG: ', msg.text()));
  await webPage.goto(url, { waitUntil: "networkidle0" });
  const pdfFileStream = await webPage.createPDFStream({
    printBackground: true,
    format: "A3",
    // margin: {
    //   top: "48px",
    //   bottom: "48px",
    //   left: "48px",
    //   right: "48px"
    // }
  });

  return {
    browser: browser,
    pdfFileStream: pdfFileStream
  };
}
```

Comment: Can you share your Puppeteer code? It's hard to help without a [mcve]. Thanks!

Comment: @ggorlen I added the Puppeteer code. Please let me know if there is anything else

Comment: Thanks. `url` would be useful, so I can run it. For PDF generation, you can use `setContent()` with the HTML. Either way, having a complete example would be great so I can run it and see the problem and begin working on a fix.